# The RegEx pattern for matching the entire specific sets of IP address class?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

The RegEx below only highlight specific Private IP addressing scheme:

```
(?!^0\.)(?!^10\.)(?!^100\.6[4-9]\.)(?!^100\.[7-9]\d\.)(?!^100\.1[0-1]\d\.)(?!^100\.12[0-7]\.)(?!^127\.)(?!^169\.254\.)(?!^172\.1[6-9]\.)(?!^172\.2[0-9]\.)(?!^172\.3[0-1]\.)(?!^192\.0\.0\.)(?!^192\.0\.2\.)(?!^192\.88\.99\.)(?!^192\.168\.)(?!^198\.1[8-9]\.)(?!^198\.51\.100\.)(?!^203.0\.113\.)(?!^22[4-9]\.)(?!^23[0-9]\.)(?!^24[0-9]\.)(?!^25[0-5]\.)(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))
```

Like in this example https://regex101.com/r/tKKYx0/3 I need to update the code to only match the Public IP addresses list on the top.

Comment: How are those addresses different from the other addresses? Please describe a rule which can actually be "coded" with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

A regex you can try is:

```
^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?=,)
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/b7HYsM/1).

Note: I did not really understand how the first IPs are different from the rest of the IPs. My regex looks for IPs at the beginning of a line, immediately followed by a comma.

Note2: My regex does not really validate IPs. E.g. 568.914.348.759 will be successfully returned.

---

For the new sample, try:

```
^(|(\S+.*?))(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/1jHGap/1).

Comment: thank you for the update. Would it be possible to match the newly updated RegEx example? https://regex101.com/r/tKKYx0/3

Comment: As I already mentioned, please explain the difference between the IPs - the ones which should match, and the ones which should not match.